# Whats is the procedure view images in a specific category from firebase database android

Tags: java, android, firebase

i don't get way to view images according my category my database will be like this

```
-id 
-category : A 
-image    : URL
```

I WANT TO SHOW A category in A category activity

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a query for that. Firebase has two databases these days and the code you need depends on which one you use.

---

If you're using the Firebase Realtime Database, the query is:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images")
                              .orderByChild("category").equalTo("A")
```

After that you need to read the results of this query, as shown in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

---

If you're using Cloud Firestore, the query is:

```
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().getCollection("images)
                               .whereEqualTo("state", "CA");
```

And then you need to read the results of this query as shown in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).